# Determinant of product of symplectic matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

In optical ray tracing it's possible to use symplectic matrices. I have a problem with them.
If a matrix $M$ is symplectic, this means that for $M$ the following equation hols:
$$M^T\Omega M=\Omega$$
where 
$$\Omega =
 \begin{pmatrix}
  0 & I_n & \\
-I_n & 0 
 \end{pmatrix}$$
The determinant of $M$ is one:
$$det(M)=1$$
If I have a product of symplectic matrices:
$$M_t=\prod_{k=1}^NM_k$$
the determinant of the product is the same way $1$.
So, how is it possible to prove:
$$det(M_t)=1$$
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use $det(AB...Z)=det(A)det(B)...det(Z)$ and the fact that $det(M_k)=1$.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what exactly you are asking. If you ask why $\det \prod_{k=1}^N M_k=1$ when $\det M_1,\ldots,\det M_N=1$, this is because the determinant function is multiplicative (i.e. $\det AB=(\det A)(\det B)$). If you are asking why a sympletic matrix has determinant $1$, this has been explained in the [related Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symplectic_matrix). If you are asking why $\prod_{k=1}^N M_k$ is sympletic, this is because
\begin{align*}
(M_1\cdots M_k)^T\Omega(M_1\cdots M_k)
&=(M_k^T\cdots M_1^T)\Omega(M_1\cdots M_k) \\
&=M_k^T\left(M_{k-1}\left(\cdots\left(M_2^T(M_1^T\Omega M_1)M_2\right)\cdots \right)M_{k-1}\right)M_k\\
&=\Omega.
\end{align*}